# Identify flag in mmap function

Tags: c, linux, mmap

```
 void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,int fd, off_t offset);
```

I see call to mmap that `prot=3` and `flags=1` what does it mean about this buffer? ,How can I translate the flag that I see in man to number?

Is the user can read/write or read+write to this buffer?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html then go find in the source code what are the values of the macros (this is implementation specific).

Comment: Which i found here: https://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/mman.h.html

Comment: If you decide to write programs above linux! You have to be tough enough to work with the terminal and type man on this function. you dont need any thing else!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question in C can be asked in two steps. First you need to read the manual to find the macros/constants you're looking for. I usually search in google for `syscall <system call>` (e.g. `syscall mmap`). Then you have to find which header file defines them and the actual header file for your implementation.

For memory map:

The manual page can be found here: 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

The header that defines the flags: 
https://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/mman.h.html

Comment: So is that mean that user can write or exec code from this buffer  but can't read from this buffer? PROT_WRITE(0x02) | PROT_EXEC(0x01) =3

Comment: Yes this is most likely what it means. The `sys/mman.h` comes from BSD I think, but it should be the same implementation on linux.